# About Java method & a parameter which implements multiple interfaces

Tags: java, function, parameters, interface

I'm writing a Java application, and have a question. How can I implement a function with **one** parameter which should require an argument which implements multiple interfaces? For example:

```
interface Father
{
}

interface Teacher
{
}

public void foo(FatherAndTeacher person) // How do I do this?
{
    // Do something
}
```

I know I can use two parameters, such as:

```
public void foo(Father person1, Teacher person2)
{
    // Do something
}
```

but I think maybe having a single parameter which implements both interfaces would be better.

Comment: I think you'll need to show a good code example. I don't find this very clear as-is.

Comment: Yes,it is possible to implement two interfaces in Java. But still it is not clear what you asking for, could you be a little bit more specific? May be by example?

Comment: I've rewritten your question to hopefully make it clearer. If I've misinterpreted your question, feel free to edit your question again :)

Comment: Thanks very much, that's right  and great! Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two enforce a parameter to have 2 interfaces you have 2 basic options:

1. Create a common interface that extends both and use that as your parameter type:

   ```
   interface FatherAndTeacher extends Father, Teacher { 
   }
   ```

   The problem with that is that objects that don't implement that interface don't match.
2. Use generics where you can require matching objects to implement both interfaces:

   ```
   public  <T extends Father & Teacher> void foo(T person) {
     // Do something
   }
   ```

   Note that this only works with interfaces, i.e. you can't do `T extends Number & String` (2 classes). It works with one object boundary though, in which case the class must be first: `T extends ConcretePerson & Father` is ok but `T extends Father & ConcretePerson` is not (where `ConcretePerson` is a class).

Comment: @Michael you're right, he didn't add it. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very very much! : )  ^v^, I get the success, and thank you very very much : )   ^v^.

Comment: @WaterMoon you're welcome. Note that you should accept one of the working answers then. :)

Comment: Sorry, first use, don't know about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a composite interface by extending both of your Teacher and Father interfaces.

Here's an example:

```
interface Teacher
{
    void teach();
}

interface Father
{
    void makeBadJoke();
}

// ----- Composite interface! Doesn't add any methods.
interface TeacherAndFather extends Teacher, Father
{
    /*This can be empty*/
}

class Bob implements TeacherAndFather
{
    public void teach() { System.out.println("1 + 1 = 2"); }
    public void makeBadJoke() { System.out.println("Knock knock..."); } 
}

class Main
{
    private static void foo(TeacherAndFather foo)
    {
        foo.teach();
        foo.makeBadJoke();
    }

    public static void main (String... args)
    {
        foo(new Bob());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great way, thank you very much.I thought this way and sometimes I want create less interface.Thanks.  : )

Comment: @WaterMoon You're welcome. Remember to click the check mark next to whichever answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

just use Object as your function parameter type:

```
void doSomething(Object param);
```

or using generic method:

```
<T> void doSomething(T param);
```

or let the two interface both inherit from one same interface.

```
public interface Person {}
public interface Teacher extends Person {}
public interface Father extends Person {}
public class Test {
    public void foo(Person p) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Except in that case you can pass things to foo that are **neither** a Teacher or a Father.

Comment: yes, the foo function itself should check where parameter is instance of Teathcer or Father

Comment: Nice to be able to enforce it at compile-time though :)